# Is there an "analog" type of tag?

Tags: support, tags

I just asked a [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/201356/105562) regarding old fashioned paper, ink and handwriting.

I notice that there are many other questions on the site concerning "analog" information security, such as involving letters, locks, ciphers used on paper, etc.

Is there any tag for questions that do not involve computers in any way?

I have been trying to search the site for such a tag, but I have not been able to find it. Perhaps it is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be far too broad a tag - there are many topics not involving computers here - so it is unlikely to ever be created. For your specific point re handwriting, analog would not be a good descriptor.